# Express $e^{cos(i)}$ in the form $x+iy$

Tags: complex-analysis

Does this seem good so far?

Since cosine can be expressed as $\frac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2i}$, $cos(i) = \frac{e^{i^2}+e^{-{i^2}}}{2i} = \frac{e^{-1}+e}{2i}$

Then $e^{cos(i)} = e^{\frac{e^{-1}+e}{2i}} = e^{i \frac{e^{-1}+e}{2}}$

I would be able to proceed from here if what I'm doing is right.

Comment: You made a mistake: $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}{2}$. This means $e^{\cos(i)}$ is a real number.

Answer (score 1):

In the last calculation, rememver that $\frac{1}{i}=-i$, so you need to add a minus in the exponent.

Other than that, you can now use Euler's formula:
$$e^{x+iy}=e^x\cdot\left(\cos y+i\sin y\right)$$